# GUI.tooltip acts weird for me

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

If i hover my mouse cursor over UIContent it does show the button "+". However the code doesnt execute when I press it. Without if(GUI.tooltip == "1") code is fine.
So what is wrong?

```
GUI.Label(Rect(700, 200, 140, 20), GUIContent(
        "test1: " + space + Static.globalTest1[qwqw], "1"));

        if(GUI.tooltip == "1")
            if(GUI.Button(Rect(800, 205, 50, 50), "+"))
            {
                level.addExp(qwqw, 50);
                /// ...
            }
```

Unity doesn't spit any compilation error.

Comment: add braces where they belong, not sure what the behavior of nested if is when the outer if doesn't have brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the tooltip system works a bit strange. The GUI.tooltip is actually set when the control is drawn. So the code responsible for setting the current tooltip is inside the GUIStyle.Draw method. That means the tooltip is only set during the Repaint event and only after the control has been drawn. So your button is drawn but won't receive any input events as the tooltip is not set when a mousedown / mouse up event is handled.

Your next problem is that your button and your label overlap. That's in general a problem since the controls are processing the events in the order the appear in OnGUI. The first control might "eat" certain events so the following controls can't process them anymore. The visibility on the other hand is reversed since the control drawn last will be on top.

Another problem is that once you move over your button (when you don't have overlap) the tooltip won't be set anymore since you left the label's area. This can simply be solved by adding the same tooltip to the Button as well.

To solve all problems you have to use a seperate variable to display your button. This should be a float so you can define a little "timeout". This will ensure that the button is visible and processed for at least the next frame. As long as you hover the label or the button the timeout variable will be re-triggered every frame and keep the button visible.

```
var tooltipTimer = 0.0;

function OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(Rect(700, 200, 140, 20), GUIContent( "test1: " + space + Static.globalTest1[qwqw], "1"));
    if (tooltipTimer > 0 )
    {
        if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
            tooltipTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(GUI.Button(Rect(800, 205, 50, 50), GUIContent("+", "1")))
        {
            level.addExp(qwqw, 50);
            /// ...
        }
    }
    if(GUI.tooltip == "1")
    {
        tooltipTimer = 1.0; // timeout 1 sec.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was huge help!